# jQuery count the number of loops made using .each function

Tags: jquery

I have a function that executes a number of times. I want to find using jQuery how many times the function is called. How do I do that?

Whenever a text field is changed, function showErrors is called. So depending on the number of text fields on a page, I should be able to find the number of times showErrors is called. how will I detect that within the showErrors function.

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {  
    if ($formEl.find(".aimInput input").length == 2) {
        // $('.validate').html(errorList[0]['message']);
        $(".aimLocal .submit").removeClass("disabled");
        $(C.options.currentPage).find('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: how does your code looks like ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var errors = 0;

(...)

showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {                                                                                                             

    if($formEl.find(".aimInput input").length == 2) {     
        // $('.validate').html(errorList[0]['message']);

        $(".aimLocal .submit").removeClass("disabled");                               
        $(C.options.currentPage).find('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");

        errors++;  // <--------------- THIS

    }                    
}
```

Then after, you can use `errors` anywhere in your code, as it's global.

Answer (score 7):

```
var i = 0;

$("div").each(function() {
    ...
    i++;
});

alert( i );
```

Comment: How about `$("div").length`?? OP says its a function.. his post title and the post is not very clear.

Comment: @Vega good point, but the handler might being called multiple times on those `divs`, so there are 3 `div`-s but the function run 9 times, for example

Comment: @Vega, you can break out of an .each() loop by returning false, or continue by returning true, so .length may not always be accurate.

Comment: @DerekHunziker check out his edited post or probably ask OP to show his code to see if doing something like that.. in this answer, there is no `return false` :P

Comment: @Vega in this answer there is a `...` that might be ANYTHING what the OP writes :)

Comment: I think the solution by Phillip Schmidt is the right way (JQ provide a var for this task). Both methods will work, but there is already an variable initialized (index). To hold your scope clean, use this.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery handles this for you. Try this:

```
$("something").each(function(index) {
    alert("Current index is " + index);
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is it, no reason declaring another var

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count the number of elements

```
$("#foo > div").length
```

Comment: I thought that too at first, but then I figured he probably was looking for a running total